# Malfunctioning on deleting from Sqlite database table (Relationship extraordinary behavior)

Tags: android, sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship

I havea weird problem in my android application which is related to database relations on foreign keys. The following codes describe my simple database's structure, 
i have used SQLiteOpenHelper as a super class for handle database operation

```
private static final String CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE __CATEGORIES_TBL(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _name TEXT NOT NULL, _desc TEXT NULL,"
                    + "_create_date INTEGER NOT NULL, _update_date INTEGER NULL"
                    + ", _parent_id INTEGER NULL, FOREIGN KEY(_parent_id) REFERENCES __CATEGORIES_TBL(_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);";

   private static final String CARDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE __CARDS_TBL(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                    + "_value TEXT NOT NULL, _play_count INTEGER NULL,  "
                    + "_category_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(_category_id) REFERENCES __CATEGORIES_TBL(_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT);";

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
            db.execSQL(CATEGORIES_TABLE);           
            db.execSQL(CARDS_TABLE);
            Logger.i("DB-INIT-DONE!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.e("Database on create error", ex);
        }

    }
```

as you see everything seems to be O.K and it is; I can insert, edit , select row(s) to/from both tables but unfortunately i can delete rows which they have child rows. 
as i expected. because i set the FK (foreign-key) relation between the tow tables with ON DELETE RESTRICT mode therefore i expect to get an exception when i try to delete a row from parent table (__CATEGORIES_TBL) , actually the parent record is deleting and no exception happens,

by theory sqlite must prevent deleting any row in __CATEGORIES_TBL when it has one or more child row(s) in __CARDS_TBL or any child row(s) in __CATEGORIES_TBL but in my application i can delete rows when it has a parent-child relationship rows,

consider the following code (this is the deleting code)

```
private SQLiteDatabase  db;
public long delete(long objId) {
            try {
                            // TABLE_NAME can be __CATEGORIES_TBL or __CARDS_TBL  based on program flow
                return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ROWID + "=" + objId, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.d("Unable to delete category <" + objId + ">.", e);
                return -123456;
            }
        }
```

every call to db.delete returns 1 (means 1 row is deleted by this command) this code is executing under android 2.3 ;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should probably create a trigger to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

I get the behavior I'd expect from SQLite 3.7.9.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE __CATEGORIES_TBL ( 
   ...>   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
   ...>   _name TEXT NOT NULL, 
   ...>   _desc TEXT NULL,
   ...>   _create_date INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   ...>   _update_date INTEGER NULL, 
   ...>   _parent_id INTEGER NULL, 
   ...> FOREIGN KEY(_parent_id) 
   ...>   REFERENCES __CATEGORIES_TBL(_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
   ...> );
sqlite> 
sqlite> CREATE TABLE __CARDS_TBL(
   ...>   _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   ...>   _value TEXT NOT NULL, 
   ...>   _play_count INTEGER NULL,  
   ...>   _category_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   ...>   FOREIGN KEY(_category_id) 
   ...>     REFERENCES __CATEGORIES_TBL(_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
   ...> );
sqlite> 
sqlite> insert into __categories_tbl values 
   ...> (1, 'name', 'desc',current_date,current_date,1);
sqlite> insert into __cards_tbl values (1, 'value',3, 1);
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys=on;
sqlite> select * from __categories_tbl;
1|name|desc|2012-08-25|2012-08-25|1
sqlite> delete from __categories_tbl;
Error: foreign key constraint failed
```

If I were you, I'd try to visually inspect the SQLite database after each step to see whether what you *expect* to happen is actually happening. IIRC, not every failure will raise an exception.

---

Foreign key support was introduced in version 3.6.19. There are [compile-time settings](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) that allow SQLite to parse foreign key constraints, but don't allow it to actually enforce them. (SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER defined, SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY not defined.) You should be able to tell whether your build of SQLite can enforce foreign keys by trying to create a trigger.

If creating a trigger fails with a parse error, then SQLite will parse foreign key statements, but won't enforce them. You'll need to recompile your build of 3.6.19, or upgrade to a newer version. (And check those settings before you compile.)

A column declared NOT NULL can appear to be empty if you've inserted an empty string. By default, NULL and empty strings look identical on output. You can tell whether a column contains nulls by selecting them.

```
select * from table_name where column_name is null;
```

Comment: you right i have tested the sql codes in 2 versions of sqlite, first one is 3.6.22 which i think it has a bug in with this issue and another one is 3.7.4 which is working properly. do i have to install new version of sqlite on my mobile ?

Comment: Another problem is about the field '_value' in table __CARDS_TBL it has a TEXT NOT NULL declaration so a row with null value to this field could not be execccuted, but in my application it is happening , i dont understand what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

about this problem i have put a db.execSQL("pragma foreign_keys=on;");  before delete statement in my app code then the problem solved, but i think this is unnecessary code maybe my phone's installed sqlite configs are wrong and needs to be reconfigured , is it possible to  reconfigure the sqlite on phone ? 
the test device is a HTC wildfire s (running sqlite version is 3.7.2)